# Compiling a Latex-Sweave child into a main Latex-Sweave file

Tags: r, knitr, sweave, rnw

I'm in the process of writing my thesis, where I have two chapters ready. I'm looking to unify those two chapters into one single Sweave file.

Suppose I have a folder called `chapter1` which contains `chapter1.Rnw`, `chapter1.tex` and `chapter1.pdf`. I usually go back to this `chapter1.Rnw`, change some stuff, compile, and look at `chapter1.pdf`.

I would like to create a new folder called `thesis` which contains `thesis.Rnw` and also the folder `chapter1`. `thesis.Rnw` would compile `chapter1.Rnw` and include `chapter1.pdf` inside `thesis.pdf`.

Right now I believe I can make it work but in a way that is not satisfactory for me.

Suppose we're in an Rstudio project where `getwd()` is `thesis/`. `thesis.Rnw` is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

<<>>=
print("Main document begins")
print(getwd()) # prints "thesis/"
@

\Sexpr{knit_child('chapter1/chapter1.Rnw')}

<<>>=
print("Main document ends")
print(getwd()) # prints "thesis/"
@
\end{document}
```

Now suppose `chapter1.Rnw` is

```
% Beginning of paper

<<>>=
print("Child document begins")
print("Child document ends")
@

% End of paper
```

Compiling `thesis.Rnw` returns the expected `pdf` but it makes `chapter1.Rnw` uncompilable on its own because it doesn't contain `documentclass{}` nor `begin{}` `end{}` documents.

I've tried including

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

% Beginning of paper

<<>>=
print("Child document begins")
print("Child document ends")
@

% End of paper

\end{document}
```

in `chapter1.Rnw` but compiling FROM `thesis.Rnw` throws a bunch of errors such as:

```
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
! LaTeX Error: Command \hlnum already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \hlstr already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \hlcom already defined.
....
! LaTeX Error: Command \hlkwd already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \kframe already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Command \knitrout already defined.
! LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.
```

Do note that running `chapter1.Rnw` using the above does work, it is now from `thesis.Rnw` that it doesn't work.

I've thought of parsing `chapter1.Rnw` from `thesis.Rnw` and removing the latex preamble before compiling but I think that could generate some errors when compiling from `thesis.Rnw` because it won't be able to find all the packages.

Is there a (easier) solution to keeping both `.Rnw` files as stand-alones but that they also work together?

Comment: I will try making child but fully compilable files with `docmute` or `standalone` packages, or control all the .Rnw to .tex conversions from in the main file, then include chapters with `\include` so you can compile easily only one-some chapters with `\includeonly` or alternatively   disabling some  \include commands preceding them by a `%`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @nebi and @Fran. I managed to solver this by reading [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/knitr/RZUGhahtTRo) forum thread and the [knitr documentation](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/child/)

The answer is really simple, actually. The `knitr` package already though about this. Everything works fine if I add

```
<<>>=
set_parent("../thesis.Rnw")
@
```

to `chapter1.Rnw`. That function will use the preamble in `thesis.Rnw` as the preamble in `chapter1.Rnw`, making both documents stand alone. I can now run `thesis.Rnw` and get the expected result and run `chapter1.Rnw` separately and get only the `chapter1.Rnw` output.

Thanks to both of you.

Answer (score 1):

A soluion, maybe not the best one, would be to keep `chapter1.Rnw` without preamble (your first solution), move part of your latex preamble in a spearate file so you can source it and have 2 masterr.Rnw files to call chapter one, one in the `thesis.Rnw` and one time in a extra 'only-chapter1'.

For example, make a tex file `package_to_include.tex`

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{...}
```

In your `thesis.Rnw`

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \input{package_to_include.tex}

 \begin{document}

<<input_chapter1, child='chapter1/chapter1.Rnw'>>=
@

 \end{document}
```

Add a new `compile_chapter_1.Rnw` for example in your your `chapter` directory

```
 \documentclass{article}
 \input{../package_to_include.tex}

 \begin{document}

<<input_chapter1, child='chapter1.Rnw'>>=
@

 \end{document}
```

To sum up, if you make the different parts modular, you can call what you need when you need it without repeating yourself. I usually also put all the R libraries i need in a separate file, so I can call it when I need it.